# The smallest numerical range of SO(N) rotation matrix

Tags: group-theory, numerical-methods, lie-algebras

In the situation of N=1, the rotation can be parameterized as $R(\theta)=e^{i\theta}$, where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. However, due to the periodic nature of rotation, we can constrain $\theta$ to sit in a small inverval like $(-\pi,\pi]$.

However, I have no idea about how to find a general constrain for arbitary N. Just like one dimentional rotation, SO(N) representations can be parameterized as:
$$
R = e^{A}
$$
Where A is an arbitary skew-hermite matrix, is it posible to find a small interval for all matrix elements so that all rotations can be represented with a limited numerical range?

Comment: $R$ is trivially a normal matrix, thus diagonizable with an orthogonal basis change matrix. From that a minimal logarithm can be computed, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227591/finding-a-set-of-logarithms-for-a-matrix-in-son